# Azure ARM provide us any way to inspect the changes

Tags: azure, infrastructure, azure-resource-manager

I am working with Azure Templates (ARM). I have to create a lot of resources and I will like to use some function to check what is going to be change in my infrastructure.

I searched a lot for any information related with this GREAT FEATURE (if there is one) but I did not find anything. So I will like to know if there is any way to see **which resources are going to be change** . I know about this for Chef and Ansible. So any suggestions or clue would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, unfortunately there is no feature to see that, but you should supply that to the [feedback site](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback). This is indeed a great idea.

Comment: Well It is pretty sad. I would like to know what is gonna happen with the new template and what is gonna be the final state of my infrastructure. Would be a great feature. Asked before here in Stack. But Thank you for your answer 4c7...!!